# iOS Swift - Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, swift

I am sure the question itself has been asked and answered properly but in Objective C. I am using swift and was wondering how to customize a UITableViewCell properly. I followed this tutorial here http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/ but I am stuck at properly initializing and using the custom class and XIB file I created. yes, I am a noob. Here is what I have for the standard cell without customization:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")
    cell.text = postMgr.posts[indexPath.section].title
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = postMgr.posts[indexPath.section].description
    return cell

}
```

If someone can translate the Obj C in the tutorial to swift that would be great. Here it is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
} 

cell.nameLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.prepTimeLabel.text = [prepTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

Not sure if that's even how it works with iOS7/8. If someone has a better and easier way of customizing the cell, let me know in Swift language.

I appreciate the help already. I am a beginner, please bear with me :)

KM

Comment: I belive that `UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")` can return nil. You need to check for that case and then create it with a regular constructor if so. What exactly is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just ported the tutorial sample app to `Swift`. I'am still using the same CustomTableViewCell written in objective-C (used bridging header to avail the class). My `cellForRowIndexPath` looks like

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
 {

    var  cell:SimpleTableCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleTableIdentifier) as? SimpleTableCell

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        let nib:Array = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("SimpleTableCell", owner: self, options: nil)
        cell = nib[0] as? SimpleTableCell
    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named:thumbnails[indexPath.row])
    cell.prepTimeLabel.text = prepTime[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

find the complete source code here: [TableViewApp-Swift](https://github.com/AnilVarghese/TableViewApp-Swift)

Comment: Thanks a lot..Worked like a charm :D (not sure why it's -1)